# Multiple matching() and contain(), condition on related records count

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

With CakePHP 3.x, I have 3 models : StudentProfile, Diploma1 and Diploma2.

- StudentProfile hasMany Diploma1
- StudentProfile hasMany Diploma2

Diploma1 has an integer "state" field.

I need to get StudentProfiles which :

- have one (or more) related Diploma1 where Diploma1.state = 2
  OR
- have one (or more) Diploma2 (no condition on Diploma2 fields)

I need to retrieve the matching Diploma1 and Diploma2 with my StudentProfiles.

I'm using the Search and Paginator components, so I have to do this with one query.

For now, I'v been able to get the first part by doing :

```
$query = $this->StudentProfiles
    ->find('search', $this->StudentProfiles->filterParams($this->request->query))
    ->contain(['Diploma1' => function ($q) {
      return $q->where(['Diploma1.state' => 2]);
    }])
    ->matching('Diploma1', function($q) {
      return $q->where(['Diploma1.state' => 2]);
    })
    ->distinct(['StudentProfiles.id'])
  ;

  $this->set('studentProfiles', $this->paginate($query));
```

Combining matching and contain allows me to add the condition and get related Diploma1 (as I understand it).

Now I need to get also all the StudentProfiles with a related Diploma2, this is where I get stuck. If I add

```
->contain(['Diploma2'])
```

...to my query, I only get Diploma2 for StudentProfiles that have a matching Diploma1 (where state=2), but I don't get StudentProfiles with related Diploma2 only (without matching Diploma1), which is perfectly normal.

So I have 2 questions :

- how can I get all StudentProfiles that have a related Diploma2 (i.e add a condition using count(...) > 0 maybe ?)
- how can I combine this with a matching clause with a condition (state=2) ?

I hope this is clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly different approach, but maybe it helps

```
$query = $this->Profile->find();

$query->select([
    'Profile.id',
    'Profile.name',
    'D1.id',
    'D1.name',
    'D1.status',
    'D1.profile_id',
    'D2.id',
    'D2.name',
    'D2.status',
    'D2.profile_id',
    'd1c' => 'COUNT(D1.id)',
    'd2c' => 'COUNT(D2.id)',
]);
$query->contain([
    'D1' => function($q) {
        $q->where(['D1.status' => 2]);
        return $q;
    },
    'D2'
]);
$query->leftJoinWith('D1', function($q) {
    return $q->where(['D1.status' => 2]);
});
$query->leftJoinWith('D2', function($q) {
    return $q;
});
$query->having(function($q) {
    return $q->or_([
        'd1c >' => 0,
        'd2c >' => 0,
    ]);

});
$query->group('Profile.id');
```

I couldn't really get `contain` to create a join, so I had to add those `leftJoinWith`

Comment: works great on my very first test :), thanks a lot for this "querying-with-cake" lesson ! I just don't understand why we need both leftJoinWith and contain, but it works.

Comment: @Flo `contain` its like a differente scope so the `main query` dont even know about the data on `contain` that's why you need use `join` instead `contain`.